# How do I remove the gun from this model?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make an SCP:CB related game. So i rigged some models and then I get to the guard model. There's a P90 that conflicts with the model. I can't remove it cause I'm a bit clumsy at blender. When I do try to remove it I always remove some parts of the hand as well. Can someone help?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t09earxu5e5oki8/guard.b3d.obj?dl=0

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I don't really know why, but here, this is the cleaned up blend file, I cleaned it manually.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11poMQAzKw_hVwS5JFI_Ep8DUoA9I8WNv/view?usp=sharing

EDIT: I'm sorry, I was just trying to help. At first, I downloaded the file and messed around with it to find an easy solution, but I can't since I'm currently not an expert. So I cleaned it up manually and send the file to help him. And, as Gordon said, this is not right, I should've gave him steps to do this himself. I'm sorry, I can't delete this answer either since it has been accepted.

Comment: This is not really a useful answer. If this would be a site to find people getting jobs done for them, okay. But simply cleaning it without explanation what you have done or how to approach this task best, the asker will not learn anything from it and especially others that might come here later will not benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped.

Comment: oh sorry, I'm just trying to help :( I will keep that in mind next time. Once again, truly sorry.

Comment: Hi. I personally appreciate that you are trying to help, awesome. However, this site is no regular forum rather a Q&A site. Link-only answers are discouraged, if the link goes down so does the answer. Please help us making this site a real 
knowledgebase and add all relevant steps to your answer, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer, Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Albert :). It's really nice of you to help others :). Please don't be discouraged by the downvotes, and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 4):

Go in *Edit* mode, select all, merge the vertices with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* because the faces are separate, then use <kbd>L</kbd> to select the different parts of the gun, and <kbd>X</kbd> to delete.

Comment: Dang.... beat me to it! :)

Comment: Thanks! Keeping this in mind next time I find a model like this!